# Bash script to print certain data from a file

Tags: bash, scripting

I have this file that is constantly gathering data from website visitors:

```
IP-ADDR : DATE : BITCOIN-ADDR
```

I was wondering if there is a way to find lines that have the same IP-ADDR but different BITCOIN-ADDR and print them.

For example, running the script on this file:

```
11.11.11.11 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am  : 3N1zXzkjYYNcUSZHD98wcG7UXjNxkCXXXX
22.22.22.22 : 19-04-2017 08:01:35am  : 1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBXXXX
12.12.12.12 : 19-04-2017 08:02:24am  : 1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBYYYY
```

every line is different, no output is printed.

Also, is very important that running on

```
11.11.11.11 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am  : 3N1zXzkjYYNcUSZHD98wcG7UXjNxkCXXXX
22.22.22.22 : 19-04-2017 08:01:35am  : 1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBXXXX
22.22.22.22 : 19-04-2017 08:02:24am  : 1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBXXXX
22.22.22.22 : 19-04-2017 08:01:35am  : 1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBXXXX
22.22.22.22 : 19-04-2017 08:02:24am  : 1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBXXXX
```

won't print anything.

BUT, running on

```
11.11.11.11 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am  : 3N1zXzkjYYNcUSZHD98wcG7UXjNxkCXXXX
22.22.22.22 : 19-04-2017 08:01:35am  : 1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBXXXX
22.22.22.22 : 19-04-2017 08:02:24am  : 1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBYYYY
```

will see that IP 22.22.22.22 has a different bitcoin address and will print:

```
1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBXXXX
1HSJDWp5gLybnhowBZcnoYTBBmuJxBYYYY
```

I'm using a code someone here helped me with a while ago:

```
awk -F " : " '{ printf "%s_%s\n" , $1, $3 }' test.txt | sort | sed 's/\(\s*\)\(.*\)\(\s\)/\2/' | uniq | perl -pe 's/(\s*)(.*?)_(.*)/\2/' | uniq -d
```

which, if run on last example, will print

```
22.22.22.22
```

but i can't wrap my head around it to make it work for bitcoin addresses.

Here are three more examples:

```
1.1.1.1 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : aaaaa
2.2.2.2 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : bbbbb

3.3.3.3 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : ccccc
3.3.3.3 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : ccccc

4.4.4.4 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : ddddd
4.4.4.4 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : eeeee
```

First example, every ip and btc is different, i don't mind.

Second example, same ip but also same btc, i don't mind that either, it's just a honest returning visitor that's using the same btc over and over, i don't want the script to show that either.

Now, third example, there is a visitor that is abusing the rules and uses different btc addr from the same ip addr. Using the script I have posted, i am able to print his ip and, through another script, to add it to an iptables firewall. But i need another script (the one i'm asking for help here) to print me the following output:

```
ddddd
eeeee
```

So i can use another script and block his access.

Some help, please? Thanks!

LE: Found the solution (thanks to @danielbmartin):

```
awk '{if (index(a[$1],$NF)==0) a[$1]=a[$1]" " $NF}
  END{for (j in a)
  {n=split(a[j],b);
   if (n>1) print j" references "a[j]}}' \
$InFile >$OutFile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
1.1.1.1 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : aaaaa
2.2.2.2 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : bbbbb

3.3.3.3 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : ccccc
3.3.3.3 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : ccccc

4.4.4.4 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : ddddd
4.4.4.4 : 19-04-2017 08:01:33am : eeeee

$ awk -F: '($1 in a) && a[$1]!=$NF{print $1} {a[$1]=$NF}' ip.txt 
4.4.4.4
```

- `-F:` use `:` as field separator
- `{a[$1]=$NF}` create an array with first column as key and last column as value
- `($1 in a) && a[$1]!=$NF` if first column is already present as key but the value doesn't match

  - `print $1` print first column

To print last column

```
$ awk -F: '($1 in a) && a[$1]!=$NF{print a[$1]"\n"$NF} {a[$1]=$NF}' ip.txt 
 ddddd
 eeeee
```

Note: this code doesn't take into consideration more than one mismatch

Comment: upvoted, well put together answer. any chance you could check out my recent question on iptables / networking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508741/iptables-script-to-block-all-internet-access-except-for-desired-applications your wisdom would be ever so helpful!